# LoadError: cannot load such file -- minitest/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I am using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.1.3, while running unit test cases with the following command

```
rake test /../test/models/file_test.rb --trace
```

I am getting the following error

```
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:run (first_time)
** Execute test:run
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- minitest/rails
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/opt/myapp/test/test_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/myapp/test/test/controllers/packager_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
/opt/myapp/test/controllers/packager_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `require'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `call'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `call'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/opt/library/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/library/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/opt/library/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.1'
```

Tried the following command as per suggestion available in SO  but still getting error.

```
require File.expand_path('../../test_helper', __FILE__) in file_test.rb
```

Also tried this way to run the test:

```
ruby -Itest test/models/file_test.rb
```

**test_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/rails"

# To add Capybara feature tests add `gem "minitest-rails-capybara"`
# to the test group in the Gemfile and uncomment the following:
# require "minitest/rails/capybara"

# Uncomment for awesome colorful output
require "minitest/pride"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  # fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if I need to provide any more explanation.

Comment: What does your `test_helper.rb` look like?

Comment: do you have the gem `gem 'test-unit'` in your gem file?

Comment: @Iceman added test_helper.rb

Comment: @Sravan No I dont have test-unit in gemfile, just have minitest

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9256, go thru this link once

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
/opt/myapp/test/test_helper.rb:4
```

What is that line?
Is it by any chance a minitest/rails include line?

Also note minitest-rails is not minitest.  If you have added minitest-rails it I would try removing it (and the include line) and see where it gets you.

Checking a fresh install of a 4.2 Rails app, I don't see such an include line in the test_helper - did you add it?  Also, minitest is already a dependency of Rails so I don't think you need to add it to your Gem file.

Comment: Yes, what is line 4?

Comment: it is **require "minitest/rails"**, also added test_helper.rb file for reference

Comment: As I thought.  Try removing it.

Comment: what is the stack trace for it now?

Answer (score 0):

The way I use Minitest is this in the `Gemfile`, notice that it's `minitest-rails`, not just `minitest`. You can of course skip `capybara` if you don't want that, but it's nice for feature/integration tests.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
end
```

and then in the `test_helper.rb`

```
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/rails/capybara"
```